# How do I draw the following vectors in the tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the following figure in a latex:[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=blue}]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1.5,1.5);
\coordinate (C) at (1.5,-1.5);
\coordinate (D) at (-1.5,1.5);

\draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\draw[->] (A) -- (C);
\draw[->] (A) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am new to tikz and I do not exactly know how to label at the end of the arrows and also the nodes with the labels c,b_1, b_2 as above. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @pikuchuchameleon Were you able to generate a part of the plot using TikZ? In this case, you should include it, so we can help you more specifically with the labels.

Comment: @Karlo: I edited and added the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=4}
\begin{pspicture}(1,-1)(4,1)
\psTangentLine[Tnormal,arrows=->,linecolor=red](2.5,0.2)(3.2,0.4)(3.8,-0.2){3.5}{0.5}
\psTangentLine[arrows=<->,linecolor=blue](2.5,0.2)(3.2,0.4)(3.8,-0.2){3.5}{0.5}
\rput[r](4,-.35){$\bf{v}_1$}
\rput[r](4,.5){$\bf{v}_2$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When posting code, please always make it into a complete minimal document.

The easiest way to add the labels is implicitly while drawing the lines. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.5,1.5);
  \coordinate (C) at (1.5,-1.5);
  \coordinate (D) at (-1.5,1.5);

  \draw [->] (A) -- (B) node [pos=.9, auto, swap] {$b_1$} node [pos=.9, auto] {$C$} ;
  \draw [->] (A) -- (C) node [pos=.9, auto] {$b_2$} ;
  \draw [->] (A) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: implicit positioning]

Or you could make the code more compact. For example, adding the `quotes` library and combining the drawing commands reduces 3 `\draw`s to 1.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge quotes/.style={pos=.9, auto}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.5,1.5);
  \coordinate (C) at (1.5,-1.5);
  \coordinate (D) at (-1.5,1.5);

  \draw (A) edge [->, "$b_1$"', "$C$"] (B) (D) edge ["$b_2$", <->] (C) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output as before.

We could even reduce the picture to a single line of code.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikz[every edge quotes/.style={pos=.9, auto}] \draw (0,0) edge [->, "$b_1$"', "$C$"] (1.5,1.5) (-1.5,1.5) edge ["$b_2$", <->] (1.5,-1.5) ;
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You draw a node simply by, say, adding

```
 \node (C1) at (1.8,-1.5) {$\mathbf{b}_2$};
```

You can do the same for the rest.